# alternative way for element-by-element multiplication for matrices in matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix, vectorization, bsxfun

I am working on a big matrix multiplication. I have a big matrix A (at least 5000x5000) and a column vector V (5000x1). In my code, each V is going to multiply each column of A element by element. I did it with a loop

```
K = zeros(5000, 5000);
for n=1:5000
  K(:, n) = V.*A(:, n);
end
```

but it is so slow. So I create a big matrix with each column assigned as V such that

```
MV=repmat(V,1,5000);
K = MV.*A;
```

it is fast but it waste too much of memory. When size of the matrix increase, it uses too much of memory. Is that any idea to use less memory but fast?

Comment: Did you pre-allocate `K` so it had the correct size?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

classic `bsxfun`

```
K = bsxfun( @times, A, V );
```

Alternatively, you might want to look at [James Tursa's](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/authors/29734) [`MTIMESX`](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/25977-mtimesx-fast-matrix-multiply-with-multi-dimensional-support) (found in FEX).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your input. it seems that bsxfun works but I need to test the efficiency later. As for MTIMESX, I read the readme but it seems for matrix multiplication only not element-by-element one.